# Compare columns' labels python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 xlsx files with multiple tabs, and each tab has multiple columns with labels.
How to check which tab has identical columns from those files?
If identical, how to show those tabs?
If not, how to show the diff?

Examples:

```
tabfile1 = [ab, ac, ad, ae, ad]
tabfile2 = [ac, bd, ae, be]

labelFile1.tab(ac) = [data, huruf, angka]
labelFile2.tab(ac) = [data, huruf, ascii, angka]
```

Comment: Please post a snippet of your data [mcve], to illustrate. Or else a screenshot of Excel.

Comment: Noted , thx @smci. Tabfile1=[ab, ac, ad, ae, ad],  tabfile2=[ac, bd, ae, be], labelFile1.tab(ac)=[data, huruf, angka], labelFile2.tab(ac)=[data, huruf, ascii, angka].

Comment: user15669504: please put that in the question, not in comments. comments are not indesexed or searchable, and likely to get deleted (ephemeral).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to read file and get to know all the tabs along with label names

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
all_files = glob.glob("*.xlsx")
for filename in all_files:
    print('Name of the file',filename)
    f = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
    sheet_names = f.sheet_names
    for sheet_name in sheet_names:
        print(f"{filename} , {sheet_name} ......")
        df = pd.read_excel(filename,sheet_name=sheet_name)
        print("{sheet_name} has following lables",df.columns)
```

Comment: Thanks @Deepak. It does show each tabs n columns. Waiting for your further share on how to check with second file.

Comment: This code can read multiple files...for this code to work both the script and file should be in the same path....you can make tweaks and use this code as per your requirement

Comment: Thank you @Deepak. Nice of you to share. If you dont mind pls share loop statement to check file1 n file2 to show which tabs with identical data labels and what is the diff for those not identical one. Appreciate it. 